# etoolbox: ifdefvoid check for empty lines

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

I designed a system that reads a number of variables and, depending on the definition creates a text (either text "a" and the text contained in the variable (macro), or an alternate text "b" when the variable is empty.) This works fine, except when the macro contains empty lines. The check (currently `\ifdefvoid`) should detect an empty macro and write text "b"
I tried a number of variants like `\ifthenelse`, `\equal...`; `\ifblank`, but none seem to work.

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{Document 1\\Document 2}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}
\\
\\

\def\foo{}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}
\\
\\Now the problem: this should also create the output "No documents"\\
\\
\def\foo{     %
%some text commented out ...

}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}
\end{document}
```

Result:
Documents:
Document 1
Document 2
no documents
Now the problem: this should also create the output ”No documents”
Documents:

edit: minimal document for error causd by 100+ ampersands:

```
    \documentclass{paper}
\newcommand{\ifdefvoid}[3]{%
  \savebox{\tempbox}{\ignorespaces #1}% Store contents in a box
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox=0pt
    #2% Width of box is zero
  \else
    #3% Width of box is non-zero
  \fi
}

\usepackage{ltablex} % tabularx
\begin{document}
\def\foo{
a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\
}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}
{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccc}
\foo
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could set the contents of `\foo` in a box with `\ignorespaces` and then test the width of the box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{paper}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newcommand{\ifdefvoid}[3]{%
  \savebox{\tempbox}{\ignorespaces #1}% Store contents in a box
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox=0pt
    #2% Width of box is zero
  \else
    #3% Width of box is non-zero
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{Document 1\\Document 2}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}

\bigskip

\def\foo{}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}

\bigskip

Now the problem: this should also create the output ``No documents''

\def\foo{     %
%some text commented out ...
}
\ifdefvoid{\foo}{no documents}{Documents:\\ \ \\ \foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks Werner! Yet if the macro contains >100 & alignment tabs (which it sometimes does, because I have to handle larger amounts of tabular data) it does not work :-( (100 errors, giving up).

Comment: @JoachimFinzel: Consider creating a minimal document that replicates this issue. Maybe we can work something out to fix your situation...

Answer (score 1):

Blank lines are translated to `\par` tokens. So we can define a macro that strips off `\par` tokens and check whether what remains only contains blanks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definedorblankorparTF}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
   {
    \__finzel_cs_if_blankorpar:NTF #1 { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   { #3 }
 }
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \__finzel_cs_if_blankorpar:N { T, F, TF }
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l__finzel_blankorpar_tl #1
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__finzel_blankorpar_tl { \par } { }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__finzel_blankorpar_tl
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__finzel_blankorpar_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\foo{Document 1, Document 2}

\definedorblankorparTF{\foo}{no documents}{Documents: \foo}

\bigskip

\def\foo{}
\definedorblankorparTF{\foo}{no documents}{Documents: \foo}

\bigskip

\def\foo{     %
%some text commented out ...

}
\definedorblankorparTF{\foo}{no documents}{Documents: \foo}

\bigskip

\def\foo{
a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\a&bla&(17.01.2019)\\
}
\definedorblankorparTF{\foo}{no documents}
{\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccc}
\foo
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks egreg! actually I was hoping for some less complicated method, but this one works fine, thanks!